# Spring queryForLong - Loss of precision

Tags: java, mysql, spring, precision

I have a Spring application running against a MySql database.  I have a sales table like:

```
+-------------------+------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type                         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Price             | decimal(19,4)                | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ItemId            | int(10) unsigned             | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

In my Spring class, I have the following:

```
long price = getSimpleJdbcTemplate().queryForLong("SELECT price FROM sales WHERE itemID = :itemID", params);
logger.info("price: " + price + ");
```

However, this is returning a price of 1, even if this query directly on the database returns **0.8500**.  How do I avoid this loss of precision from the decimal in the database to the long in my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`long` does not support decimal places because it is an integer type.  Have you tried `queryForObject(sql, BigDecimal.class, params)`?